# Conditions for convergence of transformed random variables?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, convergence

Suppose $g_{n} \to g$ and $X_{n} \to X$.
Under what conditions on the above function, random variables, and types of convergence would it be true that $g_{n}(X_{n}) \to g(X)$?

EDIT:

I am aware of the continuous mapping theorem, but doesn't the $g_{n}$ make a difference here? For example, suppose $g_{n}: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ satisfies $g_{n}(x)=x^{n}$. Then each $g_{n}$ is continuous and converges to 0 for $x \in [0,1)$ and 1 for $x=1$.

Now let $U_{n} \stackrel{iid}{\sim} U[0,1]$, and $X_{n}=U_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}\stackrel{d}{\to} 1$.

Then $g(X)=g(1)=1$ but $g_{n}(X_{n}) = U_{n} \sim U[0,1]$ for all $n$.

Comment: A hint for one of the conditions needed: $g_n$ may be continuous, but the limit function, $g$, is not.

Answer (score 2):

You basically answered this yourself: one sufficient condition is if $g_n$ converges to $g$ uniformly and also that $X_n,X$ live in a compact set, so that all continuous functions on the range of $X_n,X$ are also uniformly continuous.

Here are the details: it suffices to show that for all bounded continuous functions $f$, $E[f(g_n(X_n))]\rightarrow E[f(g(X))]$.

Notice that $h_n(x):=f(g_n(x))$ is a continuous function for all $n$. As well, for each $\epsilon>0$, by uniform convergence, $|g_n(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N(\epsilon)$. Similarly by our compact range assumption, $f$ is also uniformly continuous so lets pick an $N$ that makes $g_n$ uniformly close to $g$ and $f$ uniformly continuous:

$$h_n(x)=f(g_n(x))=f(g(x)+g_n(x)-g(x)),$$

giving:

$$f(g(x))-\epsilon\leq h_n(x)\leq f(g(x))+\epsilon.$$

Now squeeze the limit of $E[f(g_n(X_n)]$ between these two bounds and use the fact that $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, thus proving the claim.

Otherwise, if $X_n,X$ are not compact range, there could be technical problems, specifically with the non-uniformity of $f(x)$. So I think in this case you'd need at least some form of [tightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem) on $g_n(X_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most immediate answer is if each function, $g_n$, is continuous. Then, by the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem), we have that $$X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.}X \Rightarrow g(X_n)\xrightarrow{a.s.}g(X)$$
$$X_n\xrightarrow{P}X \Rightarrow g(X_n)\xrightarrow{P}g(X)$$
$$X_n\xrightarrow{D}X \Rightarrow g(X_n)\xrightarrow{D}g(X)$$

Where the mode of convergence stands for almost sure (a.s.), in probability (P) and in distribution (D).

Also, the [Portmanteau theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures) might provide some addition insight in regards to convergence of probability measures.

Comment: The continuous mapping is for *fixed* functions $g$, not varying functions $g_n$.